# VS2010 - Zip and upload to FTP

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to have Visual Studio Zip up certain files and upload them to a ftp server whenever I have a successful build?  What would be the best way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Set up a post build script to copy the various files to your FTP server. That depends on your network configuration (may be a simple copy if it is a shared drive).

Alternatively use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and have an autobuild.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, I learned a new piece of software tonight (Jenkins) :)